# Selenium 2.53.0 firefox bugging

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

So, when I try to open firefox like it either pops up really quickly, or it just stays there for a second until I can see it then crashes
Also, I use selenium version 2.53.1

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the other drivers available to Selenium from other browser vendors, [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver) has released an executable `geckodriver` that will run alongside the browser.

You need to download latest executable [geckodriver from here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and set this downloaded path from your machine as system property to run your test case with `Firefox` driver as below :

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path/to downloaded/geckodriver.exe");
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
 capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
  driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");
```