# It downloading only Selenium WebDriver 3.0.0-beta2.. 2.53.1 In selenium Web Driver i cant able to Download

Tags: selenium, webdriver

[Old Version WebDriver I can't able to download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGVyq.jpg) At present I am using 46.0 Version in Firefox and WebDriver 2.53.0 in Windows 7. It working Fine. But if I update my browser. I cant able to run the test case, it showing browser error.
   I update my Browser 47.0 & 48.0beta and used Selenium WebDriver 3.0.0-beta2 that also showing error. now, the version I cant able to download. I am just struck in this. Any solution there for this??

Comment: Similar question is shared in below link Click here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47>

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818986/selenium-2-53-0-firefox-bugging

Comment: Thanks guys i will try it.

Comment: [I am getting Error like this.  I have used `selenium Web Driver-backed 3.0.0-beta2]&  Firefox 48.0,` say what mistake i done & what i have to change.
 check the image below link] 


http://imgur.com/a/e4wIp

Please help me out