# Firefox version 48.0 is not support in selenium webdriver. Is there any solution for this?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

If I execute my code in Firefox 48.0 driver using selenium standalone jar 2.53.1, my code is not executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium 2.53.1 is not work on FireFox 48](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748675/selenium-2-53-1-is-not-work-on-firefox-48)

Comment: Refer to this issue -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium 2.53.0 firefox bugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818986/selenium-2-53-0-firefox-bugging)

Answer (score 0):

Update selenium version to selenium 3.0 or downgrade Firefox.